# Magento2 custom module downloaded by composer at two places

Tags: module, magento2, composer, git

I have hosted my custom module on bitbucket, and using satis proxy between comopser and bitbucket.
The problem is, when i use the command `composer require vendor/module`, it downloads the module at two different places,
one under the `vendors\` directory and another under the `app\code` directory, My composer.json file for the module is like this

```
{
  "name": "vendor/module",
  "description": "A Magento 2 module that creates a new page",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "extra":{
      "map":[
        [
          "*",
          "Vendor/Module"
        ]
      ]
    },
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "Vendor\\Module\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the extra.map from the composer file. Since the 2.0.0-RC version it is no longer needed as modules can now also be loaded from the vendor/ directory and don't need to be copied to the app/code directory. The registration.php file is there to register where the extension is located.

Comment: And now can develop our modules from the vendor directory? But http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/build/module-file-structure.html